# MySQL Complex Order By Specific Attribute

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL, one called users and one called attributes. The users table stores a predefined set of information about a person, such as their username and other assorted info. However, the table structure of attributes is like this:

```
+----------+---------+-------+
| username | datakey | value |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

When putting together the database, I chose to use that format because it allowed me to add arbitrary amounts of data to store for a user. However, now  I need to order users by a specific datakey 'd-level'. Since there are multiple usernames inside the attributes table, I'm unsure as to how I would proceed.

My initial thought was to use a JOIN statement to join the user table and the attributes table, but I couldn't figure out how I could get it to ORDER BY datakey only for rows that had a specific datakey ('d-level')

Thanks for your help in advance, I appreciate it!

Comment: show sample data and except result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is what you're looking for

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN attributes a 
    ON (a.username = u.username and a.datakey = 'YOUR_DATAKEY_VALUE')
ORDER BY a.datakey;
```

If not, could you please add the expected output.

Cheers,

Comment: The caveat is that I need to order it by value, but only for a row where datakey is equal to a specific value

Comment: Oh nevermind, I realized this is correct, I forgot to cast to an int